# How to insert multiple images at once

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I'm beginner in Latex, and need help, How can I, select all images on folder? I trying using the popular `/*.jpg`, but do not function

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{C:/Users/myuser/Pictures/Images/*.jpg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approch could be to rename all the images by for example *image1.jpg*, *image2.jpg*, and so on. And if so we can use *pgffor package* like this:

```
   \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{graphicx,pgffor}

    \begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
    \begin{figure} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{C:/Users/myuser/Pictures/Images/image\i.jpg} \end{figure}
}
    \end{document}
```